# How to show only three records using limit in mysql query in wordpress datatable

Tags: mysql, limit

I am using wordpress datatable but my question is that I have to show only three records But i am getting all the records this is my query

```
SELECT r.property_case
     , r.address
     , r.city
     , r.state
     , r.zip_code
     , r.country
     , r.price
     , r.bed
     , r.bath
     , r.year_built
     , r.bid_open_date
     , r.listing_period
     , u.display_name
  FROM wp_bid x
  JOIN wp_excel_report r
    ON r.id = x.p_id 
  JOIN wp_users u
    ON u.ID = x.user_id
 LIMIT 0,3
```

**It is showing all the records limit is not working on this query**

My query is working on the phpmyadmin it is showing three records in mysql but showing all the records on datatable

[image]

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept.

Comment: But aside from that, I cannot replicate this finding

Comment: @Strawberry can you write the query with three table join with limit

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this behaviour...

```
SELECT * FROM ints ORDER BY i;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * 
  FROM ints x 
  JOIN ints y 
  JOIN ints z 
 ORDER 
    BY x.i
     , y.i DESC
     , z.i 
 LIMIT 0,3;
 +---+---+---+
 | i | i | i |
 +---+---+---+
 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
 | 0 | 9 | 2 |
 +---+---+---+
```

Comment: wait letme try this

Comment: giving complete invalid results!